# Weird looking last bit in a CAN message

Tags: signal, can, bus, analysis

I did my first CAN bus design on a prototype PCB. Now I would like to verify if the CAN transceiver is working OK. So I connect a PC-CAN-USB debugger and my scope on the CAN_HIGH and CAN_LOW signal lines and send a simple CAN message from my linux CPU (*./cansend can0 -i 0x000*).

I can see that the message is received correctly in the PCCAN-USB debugger. But the signal on the scope has a very strange pattern at the end of the transmission (see picture).

[image]

In the picture you can see the complete CAN packet of this transmission at 1MBit rate. (Notice the  mandatory bit stuffing '1' after 5 consecutive '0's).

What seems to be strange is the transmission of the last bit(s):

- Can anyone explain what is happening here?
- What is the meaning of this last bit (is it some kind of acknowledge bit?)
- What could be the reason for the last bit looking so strange on the scope?
- Does this transmission look 'OK' to you?

Thanks for sharing your CAN knowledge.

Comment: What matters is the differential voltage (tell the oscilloscope to compute this). The strange-looking bit might be a consequence of two devices driving the bus to the dominant state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your voltage levels look a bit strange. CAN should ideally be 2.5V +/- 1V. You appear to have 2.3V with 3.3V at CAN HI and 0.7V at CAN LO. The 0.7V in particular is weird and might be an indication that your transceiver is acting up (post schematics please).

The last spike is another node on the bus responding to the frame with the ack field. That other node is doing a better job at staying close to the nominal voltage levels, so you see 3.5V and 1.5V voltage levels there.

Furthermore, this is no "complete CAN packet", it's just nonsense. Looks like a bunch of error frames if anything. Error frames are 6 dominant or recessive bits, whereas bit stuffing is indeed 5.

Answer (score 2):

The last bit of a CAN message is the ACK bit.

The transmitter of the packet goes to recessive state for sensing the acknowledgement, and the receiver of the packet drives the bus into dominant state to send the acknowledgement.

So that is why there is a change, the dominant state is sent by another device, and these devices have slightly different voltages.